# GDI line spacing in Delphi?

Tags: windows, delphi, text, gdi, spacing

I am trying to add character spacing to letters while drawing on a canvas in Delphi. The horizontal spacing works fine by using the `SetTextCharacterExtra` API, but if I draw text on a canvas using `DrawText` and there is a line break in it, how would I adjust the vertical spacing? I tried `SetTextJustification` but I think it only works for the space character.

Is there anyway I can adjust the vertical spacing of characters?

Comment: AFAIK you have to manually wrap and place your lines for any custom line spacing.

Comment: In [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758908/win32-drawtext-line-height) the poster is advised to use a richedit control. I don't know if it could apply to your case..

Comment: Nope i am drawing to a Canvas, there are other graphics involved plus i am drawing to a printer canvas, he suggested to use a disabled rich edit, even if the text in rich edit is formatted to fit i will still have to just take the text from there and not the rtf data and a canvas drawtext function wont understand rtf data

Answer (score 0):

[Read this comment] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1759124/2205207)

GDI uses font height and there is no way of changing it. Simply break string into lines and draw them separately.